# A group of... a team of... a pair of... a number of...: use singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

**Example 1**
A group of boys **are** ...

**Example 2**
A pair of earrings **is** ...

**Example 3**
A number of poeple **are** ...

**Example 4**
A team of scientists **is** ...

**Example 5**
This large team of volunteers **is**....

Why do we dometimes use plural sometime singular in usages like the examples?

Is there a rule of thumb or a way to think about this in native speaker's mind?

How do you decide which to use?

Comment: It is noticeable that only one of the above examples taking a singular verb has a very specific collective - namely "a pair of shoes". In the case of "a team", it sounds American to me to say "A team is". In Britain we would probably say "A team are".  These questions highlight that native speakers, who have learned English instinctively, often find it difficult to explain it by rule.  There really is little substitute for constant exposure to the language - listening, reading and speaking. But take account of whether you are listening to a British or an American voice.

Answer (score 2):

For anything involving people, we can use either the singular, to refer to the activity of the group as a whole, or the plural, to refer to the activity of the individual members of the group.

A thing, for example a shoe or an earring, is incapable of independent activity, so we should only use the singular to refer to the group as a whole. Even then, **are** is used, though relatively infrequently and in books of low literary merit.

Here are some NGram graphs that show actual usage.

[group of boys](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20group%20of%20boys%20are%2C%20a%20group%20of%20boys%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20group%20of%20boys%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20group%20of%20boys%20is%3B%2Cc0)

[team of scientists](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=team%20of%20scientists%20is%2C%20team%20of%20scientists%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20are%3B%2Cc0)

[pair of earrings](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=team%20of%20scientists%20is%2C%20team%20of%20scientists%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cteam%20of%20scientists%20are%3B%2Cc0)

[number of people](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20number%20of%20people%20are%2C%20a%20number%20of%20people%20is&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20number%20of%20people%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20number%20of%20people%20is%3B%2Cc0)